# Jhipster Ldap Integration Bad Credentials Error

Tags: spring-boot, ldap, jhipster

I am trying to integrate Jhipster with [forumsys online Ldap server](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) .But I always get **Bad Credentials** error. I get success with [spring-boot ldap sample](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/)

I have tracking this [issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10716) but it closed..

How can I solve this problem ?
thanks for your responses

**SecurityConfiguration.java** :

```
package com.test.portal.config;

import com.test.portal.security.*;
import com.test.portal.security.jwt.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    public SecurityConfiguration(TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

      
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter("(cn={0})")
    
     
      .contextSource(getContextSource());
    }
  
    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource getContextSource () {
        LdapContextSource contextSource= new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389");
        contextSource.setBase("ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com");
        contextSource.setUserDn("cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com");
        contextSource.setPassword("password"); 
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return contextSource;
    }
  
  
  
 

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
                .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
        .and()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
        .and()
            .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
        .and()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll() 
        .and()
            .httpBasic()
        .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
    }
}
```

CustomAuthenticationManager.java :

```
package com.test.portal.security;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import com.test.portal.domain.Authority;
import com.test.portal.domain.User;
import com.test.portal.repository.UserRepository;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.UserDetailsContextMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    LdapAuthenticationProvider provider = null;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationManager.class);

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private final LdapContextSource ldapContextSource;

    public CustomAuthenticationManager(UserRepository userRepository, LdapContextSource ldapContextSource) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.ldapContextSource = ldapContextSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        log.debug("AUTHENTICATION Login " + authentication.getName());
        log.debug("AUTHENTICATION Password " + authentication.getCredentials().toString());

        log.debug("AUTHENTICATION ldapContextSource > " + ldapContextSource);
        BindAuthenticator bindAuth = new BindAuthenticator(ldapContextSource);
        log.debug("AUTHENTICATION bindAuth> " + bindAuth);
        FilterBasedLdapUserSearch userSearch = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("", "(uid={0})", ldapContextSource);
        log.debug("AUTHENTICATION userSearchk> " + userSearch);
        try {
            bindAuth.setUserSearch(userSearch);
            log.debug("AUTHENTICATION bindAuth.setUserSearch> " + bindAuth);
            bindAuth.afterPropertiesSet();
            log.debug("AUTHENTICATION bindAuth.afterPropertiesSet> " + bindAuth);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.debug("AUTHENTICATION EXCEPTION>" + ex);
           // java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        provider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuth);
        log.debug("AUTHENTICATION provider>" + provider);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(new UserDetailsContextMapper() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> clctn) {
                
                Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
                GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                        "ROLE_ADMIN");
                grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);
                  return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    username, "1" , grantedAuthorities);    
            }

            @Override
            public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails ud, DirContextAdapter dca) {

            }
        });
 
        return provider.authenticate(authentication);
    }

    
}
```

ERROR MESAGE :

```
2020-08-11 15:14:02.801 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.web.rest.UserJWTController         : Enter: authorize() with argument[s] = [LoginVM{username='euclid', rememberMe=false}]
2020-08-11 15:14:02.934 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.web.rest.UserJWTController         : authorize- > euclid
2020-08-11 15:14:02.937 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.web.rest.UserJWTController         : authorize- authenticationToken> org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fa716d70: Principal: euclid; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Not granted any authorities
2020-08-11 15:14:02.941 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.s.CustomAuthenticationManager      : AUTHENTICATION Login euclid        
2020-08-11 15:14:02.953 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.s.CustomAuthenticationManager      : AUTHENTICATION Password password
2020-08-11 15:14:02.954 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.s.CustomAuthenticationManager      : AUTHENTICATION ldapContextSource > 
org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource@7e2e00ee
2020-08-11 15:14:02.960 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.s.CustomAuthenticationManager      : AUTHENTICATION bindAuth> org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator@54446f1b
2020-08-11 15:14:02.999 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.s.CustomAuthenticationManager      : AUTHENTICATION userSearchk> [ searchFilter: '(uid={0})', searchBase: '', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
2020-08-11 15:14:03.002 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.s.CustomAuthenticationManager      : AUTHENTICATION bindAuth.setUserSearch> org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator@54446f1b
2020-08-11 15:14:03.003 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.s.CustomAuthenticationManager      : AUTHENTICATION bindAuth.afterPropertiesSet> org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator@54446f1b
2020-08-11 15:14:03.008 DEBUG 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.s.CustomAuthenticationManager      : AUTHENTICATION provider>org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider@2b748549
2020-08-11 15:14:03.689 ERROR 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.t.t.web.rest.UserJWTController         : Exception in authorize() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'Bad credentials'

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:197)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:85)
        at com.turktelekom.testportal.security.CustomAuthenticationManager.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationManager.java:87)
        at com.turktelekom.testportal.web.rest.UserJWTController.authorize(UserJWTController.java:46)
        at com.turktelekom.testportal.web.rest.UserJWTController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4e6e7dd2.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)     
        at com.turktelekom.testportal.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:103)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)        
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
        at com.turktelekom.testportal.web.rest.UserJWTController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5be1eb64.authorize(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)       
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)      
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:155)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at com.turktelekom.testportal.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:38)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)      
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)       
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2020-08-11 15:14:04.197  WARN 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Bad credentials
2020-08-11 15:14:04.305  WARN 14360 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials]
```

Comment: Why do you instantiate a new LdapAuthenticationProvider for each authentication request in your CustomAuthenticationManager? It's supposed to a be singleton. Maybe Spring Boot is autoconfiguring one and you're not using the one you should. Have you checked who is calling the constructor at startup?

Comment: Jhipster suggested this CustomAuthenticationManager in the ldap documentation : https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/016_tip_ldap_authentication.html

Comment: It's a tip contributed by several JHipster users, it could be wrong. This part looks like a hack to me just to map groups to authorities while it is usually done using an LdapAuthoritiesPopulator, you should rather refer to spring securityofficial docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-ldap

Comment: Check here : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10716